# Help PHP and HTML Checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox

I need help working with Checkboxes and PHP. I'm just trying to determine a value on whether the checkbox is checked or not with PHP.

Example:

```
<?php
include ("inc/conf.php");
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

if(isset($_POST['subfrm'])){
  $gtid = $_REQUEST['tid'];

  $ch1 = $_REQUEST['ch1'];
  if($ch1 == "ON"){
    $gch1 = "Y";
  } else {
    $gch1 = "N";
  }

  $ch2 = $_REQUEST['ch2'];
  if($ch2 == "ON"){
    $gch2 = "Y";
  } else {
    $gch2 = "N";
  }

  mysql_query("UPDATE SET ctable ch1='$gch1', ch2='$gch2' WHERE id='$gtid'");
}
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="tid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ch1" />Hats
<input type="checkbox" name="ch2" />Watches
<textarea name="thetext"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="subfrm" value="PUNCH ME" />
</form>
```

Comment: and please sanitize the user input before querying the db. With your current code you are vulnerable to SQL injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["ch1"])){
    $gch1 = "Y";
} else {
    $gch1 = "N";
}
if(isset($_REQUEST["ch2"])){
    $gch2 = "Y";
} else {
    $gch2 = "N";
}
```

You don't need to check to see what the value is, because it will not submit any data whatsoever if it isn't checked, and it will submit a value of `on` if it is.

Comment: Thanks :) I also just found out that the error causing everything was the textarea info going to the SQL not the checkboxes. A simple mysql_real_escape_string() solved everything. Amazing how one error can cause a major headache. Anyway thanks. Now it's back to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
$ch1 = isset($_REQUEST['ch1']);
```

If the check box wasn't checked, its corresponding variable won't show up in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Through this together. It will let you know which checkbox was selected and it will also retain the check on form submit.

```
<?php
$message = '';
$ch1_checked = false;
$ch2_checked = false;
if(isset($_POST['submit_button'])) {
    // Form was submitted
    $ch1_checked = isset($_POST['ch1']);
    $ch2_checked = isset($_POST['ch2']);

    if($ch1_checked && $ch2_checked) {
        $message .= 'Both were checked.';
    } else if($ch1_checked) {
        $message .= 'Checkbox 1 was checked.';
    } else if($ch2_checked) {
        $message .= 'Checkbox 2 was checked.';
    } else {
        $message .= 'Neither were checked.';
    }
}
?>

<?php echo $message; ?>
<form id="my_form" action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="ch1" <?php if($ch1_checked) echo 'checked'; ?> />Checkbox 1<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ch2" value="ch2" <?php if($ch2_checked) echo 'checked'; ?> />Checkbox 2<br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Go!" />
</form>
```